# GmailApp not sending emails to gmail account every time

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, spam

I am using this code to send emails (composing email content getting text from the sheet named ranges:

```js
//compose issue emails to student and admin 
function composeIssueEmail() {

  //student's name, last name and email
  var email = ss.getRangeByName("CourseProgressEmail").getValue()
  var name = ss.getRangeByName("CourseProgressName").getValue()
  var lastName = ss.getRangeByName("CourseProgressStudentLastName").getValue()

  var subj = ss.getRangeByName("SetUpIssueTitle").getValue()
  var subject = subj.replace("*imya*", name)
  var bodyText = ss.getRangeByName("SetUpIssueBody").getValue()
  var body = bodyText.replace("*imya*", name)
  var link = getChecksheetURL()
  var text = body.replace("*link*", link)

  //send email to student
  var studentEmail = sendEmail(email, subject, text)

  var adminEmail = "AGcourseSup@gmail.com"
  var adminSubj = ss.getRangeByName("SetUpAdminIssueTitle").getValue()
  var adminSubject = adminSubj.replace("*imya*", name)
  var adminSubjectFinal = adminSubject.replace("*familia*", lastName)
  var adminText = ss.getRangeByName("SetUpAdminIssueBody").getValue()
  var adminTextReplace = adminText.replace("*imia*", name)
  var adminBody = adminTextReplace.replace("*familia*", lastName)
  var adminText = adminBody.replace("*link*", link)

  //send email to admin
  sendEmail(adminEmail, adminSubjectFinal, adminText)
}

//gets current checksheet URL
function getChecksheetURL() {

  var Url = ss.getUrl()
  var linkMiddle = "#gid="
  var sheetID = sheet.getSheetId()

  var shecksheetURL = Url + linkMiddle + sheetID

  return shecksheetURL
}

//sends emails
function sendEmail(email, subject, body) {

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)

}
```

**Execution transcript:
[19-06-12 16:39:43:396 EEST] Execution succeeded [2.399 seconds total runtime]**

It sends stably to the gmail account that is the same as spreadsheet's one.

But **to another gmail account it sends about every other time.**

**Details:**

- This code is executed (I log the line after this code)
- The emails are visible in my outbound box but not arriving to any of the boxes of the recepient gmail.
- Not in spam etc.
- I don't get any messages, error or bounce notifications.

I tried MailApp instead - it's even worse and sometimes doesn't send even to my own email.

I tried to change things in settings config, but didn't find anything to work.

I set up a filter "never send to spam" and "always star it" - didn't work.

I deleted a link from it so it has no link - didn't work.

What can be a solution?

Comment: Include the rest of your code - it could be something other than your `sendEmail()` line causing this.

Comment: Are there any messages in the Execution Transcript? Where are you getting the value for `email` from; a spreadsheet or the like which may have an incorrect string?

Comment: @Altigraph it says Execution succeeded and shows that email was sent. And I see in in Sent section of gmail. But it didn't reach the recipient inbox. Sometimes does, sometimes not.

Comment: Please include the execution transcript in your post and show the rest of your code, especially explaining where `email` is coming from.

Comment: @ross no other special algorithms simply composing an email and a subject (which works well) and then this line. Nothing else.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: If the emails are always in your "sent" folder, then I'm wondering if this problem is with the computer system within the organization that the Apps Script file is running in.  Do emails need to go through some kind of internal system inside of the organization?

Comment: @Alan both are regulat gmail accounts. Is there an option in email settings (config) I can check?

Comment: Is the code ever run multiple times in rapid succession?  Like multiple users all doing the same thing at the same time.  If so, it could be a concurrency issue.  But, in any case, I'd add some error handling with `try{ //my code }catch(e){//what to do if error}`  For small scripts like this, and since it's in a spreadsheet, you could just put `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().appendRow(['error',e.message,e.stack])`  into the catch block of the try/catch. The Execution Transcript is good, but you need something more when debugging a problem like this.

Comment: @AlanWells no multiple succession, only me running the code. As for the try catch good point but it doesn't go to catch block. The code is executed well and starts sending emails. I see that deliverability is not the code concern)) So I see the problem is withing the email account. It is G Suite account and a pretty fresh one. Created a few month ago but haven't been used other than for testing purposes. I will test it with some old account.

Comment: tried with another old good email account that has worked for many years and same thing. That's a major issue, because I am gonna send many email notifications to clients! It sends stably only to my own email account. Tried few others and same problem. Who knows how to handle?

Comment: It's possible that this is an Apps Script bug.  I was just contacted by a user of one of my add-ons, who is experiencing the same problem.  Some emails are being sent intermittently, some not at all.  I have not updated the add-on for a long time.

Comment: I tried to send same emails manually from different email accounts and same thing. Only to native account they get ok. So it's an email issue, some anti spam filters. But it's so connected to the code and work for clients. I'd like to know how to make all emails reach destination.

Comment: Hi @kiki, would you be able to give us a sample of the subject & body just to know what it looks like? Also, when you get the values for the student's information, are you trying to get a single user's data? If so, where are you setting the range name to look for a particular one? Last, Does the error also happens when you email yourself? or is it just when you try to email the student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handled this issue. The issue is about anti-spam filters not about the code.

I gained more trust to the email account by adding "Reply To" option within  `GmailApp.sendEmail` method. It magically solved the problem so each email reaches target now.